# using render_async to render new messages in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm setting up [render_async](https://github.com/renderedtext/render_async) to use as a temporary hotfix for the fact that I can't get ActionCable to work without mysterious server-destroying response times, and need a little help understanding the docs. The way I have it set up (which I believe is line with their suggestions) renders the *entire page* inside a div instead of rendering new messages as they are submitted. How would I make it so that it works as I intend?

**routes.rb**

```
resources :conversations, only: [:index, :create], path: "chats" do
 resources :messages, only: [:index, :create]
end
```

**messages_controller.rb**

```
def index
 @conversations = Conversation.participating(current_user).order('updated_at DESC')
 @messages = @conversation.messages.all
 @message = @conversation.messages.new

 if !@conversation.unread_message_count(current_user).zero?
    @conversation.mark_as_read(current_user)
 end

 # render partial: "messages/message" 
 # (the docs suggest rendering the partial here, but i want it rendered in a div, not the entire window)
end
```

**messages/index.html.erb**

```
<%= render_async conversation_messages_path %>
```

**_message.html.erb**

```
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
    <% cache message do %>
        <div class="message">
            <div><strong><%= message.user.username %>:</strong> <%= message.body %></div>
            <div class="date"><%= local_time(message.created_at) %></div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey, what do you see when you use the code you posted? Is it loading the index page properly or what is going on? P.S. I'm the author and maintainer of the gem, I can help you out if you're still having problems.

Comment: @NikolaĐuza Thank you for following up, but I should close this issue! Turns out I didn't need the gem. The Logentries addon for Heroku mislabels the open websockets connection as a high response time error, and the basic ActionCable setup works just fine.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the reply!